# SQL Service Analysis Service - Process Full in Visual Studio?

Tags: ssas, azure-analysis-services

I am working on a SSAS tabular model in Visual Studio which I have imported from our SSAS server.

I have noticed that at the top I can select process - process full, table etc..

Just wondering, do these only process the model stored in my visual studio? And not the model that is live on the server? I can't find anything online that specifies this..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it only processes the one shown in Visual Studio (called workspace version):

> Model menu can be used to... ...process workspace data...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/tabular-model-designer-ssas?view=asallproducts-allversions#menu-items